# I have implemented a javascript image cropping feature using html canvas. It is working perfectly on chrome and IE(?!), but not on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, drawimage, todataurl

https://jsfiddle.net/1gf6xzyz/3/
is the link to the fiddle. I will point to important points in the JS code with what is being tried.

line 22 : it is where i attach the cropper to the image object. the cropper is a class which takes the reference to the image and options that have self-explanatory names. The important ones are:

- ratioDim - aspect ratio of the crop window.
- maxCaptureWidth - the maximum width of the image that can be cropped.

  ```
  cropper = new Cropper.Img('imgSelector', {
                      minWidth : 120,
                      minHeight : 90,
                      ratioDim : {
                          x : 120,
                          y : 90
                      },
                      displayOnInit : true,
                      imageDataCallback : imageDataCallback,
                      maxCaptureWidth : 400,
                  })
  ```

The crop library starts at line 47. I have adapted an existing [library](http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/) to suit my needs.

line 357 - this is where the cropper is attached to the image after it has loaded. the transformation that happens is listed from 358 to 386.

```
    onLoad : function() {
            /*
             * Build the container and all related elements, will result in
             * the following
             * 
             * <div class="imgCrop_wrap"> <img ... this.img ... /> <div
             * class="imgCrop_dragArea"> <!-- the inner spans are only
             * required for IE to stop it making the divs 1px high/wide -->
             * <div class="imgCrop_overlay imageCrop_north"><span></span></div>
             * <div class="imgCrop_overlay imageCrop_east"><span></span></div>
             * <div class="imgCrop_overlay imageCrop_south"><span></span></div>
             * <div class="imgCrop_overlay imageCrop_west"><span></span></div>
             * <div class="imgCrop_selArea"> <!-- marquees --> <!-- the
             * inner spans are only required for IE to stop it making the
             * divs 1px high/wide --> <div class="imgCrop_marqueeHoriz
             * imgCrop_marqueeNorth"><span></span></div> <div
             * class="imgCrop_marqueeVert imgCrop_marqueeEast"><span></span></div>
             * <div class="imgCrop_marqueeHoriz imgCrop_marqueeSouth"><span></span></div>
             * <div class="imgCrop_marqueeVert imgCrop_marqueeWest"><span></span></div>
             * <!-- handles --> <div class="imgCrop_handle imgCrop_handleN"></div>
             * <div class="imgCrop_handle imgCrop_handleNE"></div> <div
             * class="imgCrop_handle imgCrop_handleE"></div> <div
             * class="imgCrop_handle imgCrop_handleSE"></div> <div
             * class="imgCrop_handle imgCrop_handleS"></div> <div
             * class="imgCrop_handle imgCrop_handleSW"></div> <div
             * class="imgCrop_handle imgCrop_handleW"></div> <div
             * class="imgCrop_handle imgCrop_handleNW"></div> <div
             * class="imgCrop_clickArea"></div> </div> <div
             * class="imgCrop_clickArea"></div> </div> </div>
             */
    .......
    }
```

line 574 - the initial part of this function tries to set the max dimentions of the image to fit according to the supplied "maxCaptureWidth". The rest of the function calculates the topleft and bottom right coordinates for the crop area in relation to the image.

```
    var ratioOfContainer = this.img.naturalHeight
                    / this.img.naturalWidth;
    var baseWidth = (this.img.naturalWidth > this.options.maxCaptureWidth) ? this.options.maxCaptureWidth
                    : this.img.naturalWidth;
    var corelatedHeight = baseWidth * ratioOfContainer;

    this.img.width = baseWidth;
    this.img.height = corelatedHeight;

    this.imgW = baseWidth;

    this.imgH = corelatedHeight;
```

line 656 to 658 - these are the main functions that are responsible for capturing the image onto a canvas. selArea is the area that will be drawn onto the canvas.

```
    this.selArea.show();
    this.drawArea();
    this.endCrop();
```

line 758 - utility to get the cropper width.

```
    calcW : function() {
        return (this.areaCoords.x2 - this.areaCoords.x1);
    }
```

line 768 - utility to get the cropper height.

```
    calcH : function() {
        return (this.areaCoords.y2 - this.areaCoords.y1);
    }
```

line 1170 - the draw area is the function that is guaranteed to get called if the cropper is resized or moved. it is responsible for applying the styles on the image overlay according to the current cropper position.

line 1230 - the draw to canvas functionality starts here. This part works fine in both IE and Chrome. In firefox, it only works when the cropper top left coincides with the image top left. And movement of the cropper vertically or horizontally distorts the captured image. I have checked the parameters that are passed to the context's drawimage function thoroughly and see no issues there.

```
    var ratioDimHeight = this.img.naturalHeight / this.img.height;
    var ratioDimWidth = this.img.naturalWidth / this.img.width;

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = areaWidth;
    canvas.height = areaHeight;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");              

    context
            .drawImage(
                    this.img,
                    this.areaCoords.x1 * ratioDimWidth,
                    this.areaCoords.y1 * ratioDimHeight,
                    this.img.width * ratioDimWidth,
                    this.img.height * ratioDimHeight,
                    0, 0, this.img.width,
                    this.img.height);
    this.imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

line 1252 - i extract the cropped image as a dataurl and further send it to the server side using ajax, on form submit and upload the image bytes to s3.

I have no idea why it won't work with firefox and will greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance for your consideration.

Comment: did you use some kind of debugger? can you be more specific then "it won't work"?

Comment: i used a debugger to validate the coordinates, yes. I wish i could put it better than "it wont work" :) If you see the fiddle, the image is being cropped, but it soon gets distorted when the top left of the cropper and the image don't coincide.

Comment: I'm the creator of the JS although it's quite old I just tested your jsfiddle link in Firefox 32.0.3 (OS X) and latest Chrome. Apart from an error when I click the "CROP" text (Uncaught ReferenceError: makeCropperInVisible is not defined) the cropper is working for me in both browsers.

What is the actual issue you are seeing?

Comment: Thank you sir for a very neat library. I loved your work.
http://s29.postimg.org/xvvj8zdlj/chrome.png and http://s12.postimg.org/5otsuhovh/firefox.png

Comment: The images will better explain what i am trying to convey. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The change that works for me is the following :

```
           this.img.width = this.img.width - this.areaCoords.x1;
           this.img.height = this.img.height - this.areaCoords.y1;
           context
                    .drawImage(
                            this.img,
                            this.areaCoords.x1 * ratioDimWidth,
                            this.areaCoords.y1 * ratioDimHeight,
                            this.img.width * ratioDimWidth,
                            this.img.height * ratioDimHeight,
                            0, 0, this.img.width * ratioDimWidth,
                            this.img.height * ratioDimHeight);
           this.imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

           this.img.width = this.img.width + this.areaCoords.x1;
           this.img.height = this.img.height + this.areaCoords.y1;
```

I have to reduce the image dimensions according to the crop window dimentions. Somehow firefox correlates the canvas capture with the image dimensions which is different to other browsers. I wish i could say i solved it in some clever way but :) I played around with the drawimage function and observed how it behaves and arrived at this "hack". Maybe it is useful for someone.

Thanks again DEfusion for the neat cropping library.